# How to remove automatic loading of packages when starting RStudio?

Tags: r, package, rstudio

Every time I startup RStudio, there are some packages that automatically load before I start coding. Is there a way that I can remove that option? I prefer to manually load the packages that I want to use and this automatic load creates problems when I update a package because when doing an update, RStudio asks to restart the software to unload any open package but when it restarts it does the automatic load of some packages. Does anyone have this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Which packages? There are a handful that are a part of base R itself (e.g. utils). RStudio will load others sometimes if you load an environment from an old session that contains objects from a package. Removing the objects or not saving the workspace will avoid that. And obviously don't load stuff in `.Rprofile` if you don't want it to be loaded

Comment: It’s the ‘trajectories’ and ‘mapview’ packages. They automatically load when I startup RStudio. I’m not that familiar with .Rprofile because I just open RStudio, do my coding and save the script only. I will take a look on that. Thanks!

Comment: Look at "Preferences" > "General" > "Basic" > "Restore .RData into workspace at startup". If that's checked (the default), it'll reload all the stuff you assigned to your global environment last time, which may be causing the issue.

Comment: This worked! I've unchecked that option and when I opened RStudio again, it startup quickly and the console window was clear. Thank you so much! But for latest versions of RStudio, the "Preferences" tab doesn't exist. You have to go to "Tools" > "Global Options". A window will open with different tabs, including "General" where these options are found. Thanks again for all your help!